# Selection with where clause using generics C#

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, generics

I have an application (xamarin) with a database connection using sqlite (sqlite-pcl-net). I have written my methods for retrieving data from the database using specific classes. But I am interested on how to write these using generics?

The method I have and want to make use of generics with is the following: (results in a User class)

```cs
public Task<User> GetUserByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return Database.Table<User>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Now I need to have the same thus, resulting in a class T but the id keeps the same (function parameter keeps an int).
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your classes (`User`...) have to either implement a common interface or inherit from a base class (with an `Id` property) to allow this. Then you can use generic constraints to implement the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **@vc 74** pointed out in comment section, you can implement a common interface or inherit from a base class with an `Id` property:

```
public Task<T> GetUserByIdAsync<T>(int id) where T : BaseEntity
{
    return Database.Table<T>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Or you can use [Expression Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries):

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string filterField)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, filterField);
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
    Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
    var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "where", types, q.Expression, exp);
    return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
}
```

The implementation for this extension method would something like  `Database.Table<User>().WhereByField("Id");`:

Comment: `Database` probably only knows abouts concrete classes so you need `public Task<T> GetUserByIdAsync<T>(int id) where T : BaseEntity`

Comment: @ronanvanderveken you are welcome, please mark answer as accepted if it solved your problem so that it helps the other people.